# Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class for @WebMvcTest and @DataJpaTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, junit, h2

I have an entitie `PetBE` and I want to write an end to end test where a request updates the database.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "pets")
public class PetBE {
    
    @Id
    private long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;

}
```

It works fine if I just test the database

```
@DataJpaTest
public class SetupTests {

    @Test
    @Sql("onePet.sql")
    void dummytest() {
        assertThat(1).isEqualTo(1);
    }
}
```

or just a request but the database is mocked. However when I try both, I get an error:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = PetController.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class E2ETest {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private PetRepository pr;

    @Test
    @Sql("onePet.sql")
    void whenPetExists_thenReturns200() throws Exception {
        //mockMvc.perform(put("/pet")...
        assertThat(1).isEqualTo(1);
    }
}
```

namely

```
Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.example.petstore.backend.api.implementation.E2ETest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper)]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.example.petstore.backend.api.implementation.E2ETest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper)]
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveExplicitTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:166)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:127)
```

It seems like `@WebMvcTest` and `@DataJpaTest` are mutually exclusive, but I clearly need `@WebMvcTest` and without `@DataJpaTest` I get

```
Failed to execute SQL scripts for test context [DefaultTestContext@703ec858 testClass = E2ETest, testInstance = com.example.petstore.backend.api.implementation.E2ETest@1005e0c5, testMethod = whenPetExists_thenReturns200@E2ETest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@678e04d0 testClass = E2ETest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.example.petstore.PetstoreApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@74ce371b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@3ca253f3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@117223fd, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@4b5bf35f, [ImportsContextCustomizer@5ff8aba2 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5cbc6bb6, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@2641cd8, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@e1051f26, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]: supply at least a DataSource or PlatformTransactionManager.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute SQL scripts for test context [DefaultTestContext@703ec858 testClass = E2ETest, testInstance = com.example.petstore.backend.api.implementation.E2ETest@1005e0c5, testMethod = whenPetExists_thenReturns200@E2ETest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@678e04d0 testClass = E2ETest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.example.petstore.PetstoreApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@74ce371b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@3ca253f3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@117223fd, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@4b5bf35f, [ImportsContextCustomizer@5ff8aba2 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5cbc6bb6, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@2641cd8, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@e1051f26, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]: 
supply at least a DataSource or PlatformTransactionManager.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
    ...
```

So I think I need this one as well. How can I get those two annotatins to work together?

Comment: That's not possible. You must use Spring Boot Test https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are mutually exclusive as `@DataJpaTest` contains `@BootstrapWith(DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper.class)` and `@WebMvcTest` contains `@BootstrapWith(WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper.class)`.

You need to replace `@DataJpaTest` with `@AutoConfigureDataJpa`, `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` and `@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager`.

And eventually replace `@WebMvcTest` with `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` if you need dependency injection like a service between your controller and your repository.

Exemple:

```
/*
    We cannot use @WebMvcTest(BookingController.class) as we need the injection of the component used by the BookingController (BookingService)
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc is necessary for the MockMvc instantiation.
 */
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = BackendApplicationTest.class)
/*
    We cannot use the @DataJpaTest annotation
    Otherwise we will have the error "Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith" (present in @SpringBootTest and @WebMvcTest)
    But we need the @AutoConfigureDataJpa, @AutoConfigureTestDatabase and @AutoConfigureTestEntityManager annotations to autowire the BookingRepository
 */
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
@Sql({"/sql/insert-rooms.sql", "/sql/insert-accounts.sql", "/sql/insert-five-reservations.sql"})
// Reset the h2 database state after each test, otherwise the insert will be done twice and will fail
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class BookingControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_fetch_reservations() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc
                .given()
                .auth().with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user("user-test").roles("USER"))
                .when()
                .get(ControllerConstants.CONTROLLER_BOOKING_ENDPOINT)
                .then()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                .body("$.size()", Matchers.equalTo(5));
```

Where `/sql/insert-five-reservations.sql` contains:

```
INSERT INTO reservation(id, start_time, room_id, account_id) VALUES (1, '2022-02-21 08:00:00', 2, 1);
INSERT INTO reservation(id, start_time, room_id, account_id) VALUES (2, '2022-02-21 09:00:00', 2, 1);
INSERT INTO reservation(id, start_time, room_id, account_id) VALUES (3, '2022-02-21 10:00:00', 2, 2);
INSERT INTO reservation(id, start_time, room_id, account_id) VALUES (4, '2022-02-21 11:00:00', 2, 1);
INSERT INTO reservation(id, start_time, room_id, account_id) VALUES (5, '2022-02-21 14:00:00', 2, 2);
```